# What are these timings shown next to lines of the script in Sources panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: img]

What are these timings shown next to lines of the script in Sources panel? I couln't find anything in the devtools documentation...

Comment: Can you show content of these lines or something similar so that we could find some pattern? Are there some `async/await` operations? That line with `0.1 ms` looks like some `observable`

Comment: Most likely it measures the delay/performance of each line of code. Maybe you have enabled some debugging feature. Notice that the color gets darker the longer the duration is.